# What to take from representation of $S_d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, intuition

I am reading about group representations, and books I read all contain the representation theory for symmetric groups $S_d$. However none of them presents the material in a friendly way. After reading them, I felt quite dazzled by the brilliance of the arguments (Young frames, Frobenius formular for characters, etc.) but do not really feel they deepened my understanding of group representations.

I know Cayley's theorem gives some theoretical importance to the representations of $S_d$. But what should I take from them indeed? What should I learn from the arguments? Do they really teach us something deep/ general?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your goal in studying representation theory?  Which part of it has taught you something deep/general?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Theorems that can be applied to many situations? Do techniques used in representations of $S_d$ appear somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, they appear in lots of somewhere elses: algebraic geometry, invariant theory, combinatorics...The point is that "Why is X important?" is usually a relative question in mathematics.  If you tell us what you already know and what your motivations are, we have a much better chance of connecting representations of symmetric groups with things of interest to you.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks! I am rather new to representations and have just gone through first six chapters in Barry Simons' *Representation of Finite and Compact Groups* and the first four chapters of Fulton and Harris' *Representation Theory, a First Course*. I do not really have a specific motivation behind my reading representations. I worked a lot in operator theory and harmonic analysis, and it seems to me the abstract part of harmonic analysis has a lot to do with representations, and that is why I start to read about representation theory.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark BTW, I just learnt today that representations of $S_d$ appear as factors of sub-representations of tensor products (Weyl construction). Since all irreps of finite groups can be found in tensors of faithful representations, this gives me a little hint of the usefulness of rep. of symmetric groups.